# Cannot Install Microsoft.Extenstions.Logging Nuget Package, on .Net Framework 4.6, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, nuget-package, .net-framework-version, .net-standard

I am trying to install the Nuget package: Microsoft.Extenstions.Logging, on my ASP.Net MVC 5 projecton, .Net 4.6, Visual Studio 2015, and keep getting this error:

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.2.0.0' with respect to project
>   'ProjectName.web', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' Gathering
>   dependency information took 271.03 ms Attempting to resolve
>   dependencies for package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.2.0.0'
>   with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest' Resolving dependency information took
>   0 ms Resolving actions to install package
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.2.0.0' Resolved actions to install
>   package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.2.0.0' Retrieving package
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0' from 'nuget.org'.   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration/2.0.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.2.0.0.nupkg
>   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration/2.0.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.2.0.0.nupkg
>   259ms Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0. Install
>   failed. Rolling back... Package
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.2.0.0' does not exist in project
>   'ProjectName.web' Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.2.0.0' does
>   not exist in folder 'C:\Git\ProjectName\packages' Executing nuget actions
>   took 1.27 sec Could not install package
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   ========== Finished ========== Time Elapsed: 00:00:05.6980685

Here is another link to this problem, on Github: [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/313)

But does not provide any solution/workaround to fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out that there are two things to watch for when installing: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (and many other Microsoft.Extensions.*)...

The first issue is that you need  Nuget Version 4.3.0 or higher to be able to install this package. Since I was using visual studio 2015, which comes with lower version of Nuget, I had to install: [https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/v3.6.0/NuGet.Tools.vsix][1]

Or I could upgrade to Visual Studio 2017, which comes with Nuget 4.4.0.

The second problem that I had was that initially my .Net Framework version was 4.5, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging has a dependency on .NetStandard 2.0 and therefore, if you are using .Net Framework, you need version 4.6.1 or higher.

In my case, I installed VS 2017, changed the Target Framework to .Net Framework 4.6.1 and finally I could install the Nuget Package.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for this! Wish it was more clear on the PM!

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach and it worked for me!

1. While in Visual Studio, Navigate to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > General
2. Click on "Clear All NuGet Cache(s)"
3. Wait for process to complete and click Ok

Now retry installation of packages, should work ok :)